# SQL Server - how to disable case sensitive in my query window?

Tags: sql-server

Is there some way to disable case sensitive in my SSMS Query Window?

For example, in some customers I get the following error:

```
USE TEMPDB
GO
.....
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Database 'TEMPDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

But if change to lower case the command works.

```
USE tempdb
GO
...
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Is this configuration related to database collation? is there some way to change the behavior only in my session? this is very annoying because isn't at data level only, but in object level as well. For example, the same happens when I try to select some view (S in uppercase).

```
select * from sys.Sysaltfiles
....
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.Sysaltfiles'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably those instances are case sensitive. FWIK there is no way to ignore it in SSMS and that is good as the case sensitive collation enables you to have objects with the same name but different case (dbo.Table1 is not the same as dbo.table1).

Single databases can have a different (case insensitive) collation but the tempdb inherits the instance collation.